# How to Remove Server Header .NET Core Blazor app

Tags: security, .net-core, header, blazor

I tried lot of things but none of them worked...
Is there a simple way to remove the server name in the header?
[image]

I work in blazor server side environment, IIS 8.5

I created a web.config and tried with -> requestFiltering removeServerHeader="true" tag
[image]

but then impossible to access to the web app, I get an "500 - Internal server error."

I tried with nuget NWebsec middleware package and adding to program.cs :
"webBuilder.UseKestrel(options => options.AddServerHeader = false);"
[image]

Nothing works ...

Comment: Investigate that 500 error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find the solution :

1. add a web.config file in your project with visual studio (add item, search for web configuration).
2. add in the webconfig file those line after "aspNetcore" tag and before the "system.webserver" end tag :

   ```
   <rewrite>
        <outboundRules>
            <rule name="Remove Server Response Header">
                <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_SERVER" pattern=".*" />
                <action type="Rewrite" />
            </rule>
        </outboundRules>
    </rewrite>
   ```

NB: you supose to have the re write extension already installed on your IIS